# additional row for percentage of points in package exam

Tags: exam

**MWE**

```
 \documentclass[addpoints ,12pt]{exam}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\pagestyle{head}

\runningheader{\class}{\examnum\ - Page \thepage\ of \numpages}{\examdate}
\runningheadrule

\pointname{ Pkt.}
\marginpointname{|\hspace{2mm} Pkt.}
\qformat{\small Q \thequestion  \dotfill {\totalpoints\ |............ Punkte}}

\begin{document}
    
    
    
    \begin{center}  
        \gradetable[h]
    \end{center}


    \begin{questions}
    
    
    \question $2+2=4?$
    
    \begin{parts}
        \part[3] {
            $f(x)= \cfrac{1}{2x-7}$}
   \end{parts}
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

**Current output**
[image]

I would need an additional row for percentage of points under the Points row. Is something fulfilling this request implemented in this package? If not, what are the other solutions?

**An similar screenshot of what I need** (**new row is in red** - but, I want the solution in black - red was for highlighting):

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Please clarify what you want to achieve and provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that). It will increase you chances of getting an answer.

Comment: @Roland I doubt if he wants an line under the *points* feature which is implemented in the exam packages, nevertheless, I do wonder whether these new users don't get what meant by https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions or basically ignore the comments (or no notifications?)

Comment: Hello, Welcome to Tex.SE! We can't find what you state by *points*? We have to know a little bit of code how the *points* is generated [with the exam package].  Can you draw up a little picture of what you want? A [lil' bit of code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) is preferred with a Screenshot, if you can.

Comment: Sorry, now you can see my code

Comment: @ user255280 For future questions please keep the MWE minimal. You should not load packages more than once and also do not load unnecessary packages.

Comment: **If you have time and data(load at non-peak time)** look at this: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/exam/examdoc.pdf

Comment: The screenshot seems to mix English and German (according to an ai translator of my choice). Is this on purpose?

Comment: @CampanIgnis No, I think his main language is german but he uses most english words or some english words are similar.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know much about exam class, but with `\chbpword{<name>}` you can give bonuspoints a different name. Maybe this works for you.

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}

\begin{document}

    \chbpword{Percentage}
    
\begin{center}
    \combinedgradetable[h][questions]
\end{center}

 
    \begin{questions}
        \question[2] 
        $2+2=?$

        \question[2] 
        $1+2=?$
    \end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]